# Alternative for OptaPlanner (Constrain Solver) in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, constraints, optaplanner

Cheers Community,

I would like to build a lesson planner and am looking for a constrain solver in NodeJS. Currently I have found [OptaPlanner](https://www.optaplanner.org/) as a Java variant.

Does anyone have experience with constrain solvers in NodeJs environment and maybe with timetables?

Current constrains are:

- Classes
- rooms
- subjects
- Teachers
- timeslots

the idea behind the constraint solver should be an automatic assignment of subjects/teachers/classes within given timeslots.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there are is no pure JavaScript alternative for OptaPlanner yet. But OptaPlanner works in Kotlin or Java and OptaPy works for Python.

What you might be able to do, is take the [quarkus school timetabling](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/school-timetabling) quickstart, compile it natively (see readme) to avoid requiring a JDK in production and call that from Node.js?